# Creating new dataframe from existing dataframe columns if not empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns that contain data for some rows and not for others. I need to merge several columns into a single column, removing missing data. For example:

```
   Name     Preference_1 Preference_2 Preference_3 Preference_4
0  Dave        Beach         Lake     Mountain       Desert
1  Jeff     Outdoors          NaN          NaN          NaN
2   Tom       Forest        Ocean        Swamp          NaN
```

Needs to become this:

```
   Name   Preference
0  Dave      Beach
1  Dave       Lake
2  Dave   Mountain
3  Dave     Desert
4  Jeff   Outdoors
5  Tom      Ocean
6  Tom      Swamp
7  Tom     Forest
```

Comment: why do `Ocean`, `Swamp` move from `Tom` to `Jeff` in the output?

Comment: you want [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: @AndyL. You're right that was a typo thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
( df.melt('Name',value_name='Preference')
    .drop('variable',axis=1)
    .dropna()
    .sort_values('Name')
    .reset_index(drop=True) )
```

or [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.set_index('Name').stack().rename('Preference').reset_index(level=['Name',0],drop=0)
```

**Output**

```
   Name Preference
0  Dave      Beach
1  Dave       Lake
2  Dave   Mountain
3  Dave     Desert
4  Jeff   Outdoors
5   Tom     Forest
6   Tom      Ocean
7   Tom      Swamp
```

Comment: Thank you very much